# Firefox Web extension. Accessing popup content in content script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Directories

```
----MyExtension
     |----popup.html
     |----popup.js
     |----content.js
     |----background.js
     |----manifest.json
```

mainfest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
 ...........
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "js": ["content.js"]
  }
 ],
 "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Practice",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
"permissions": [
 "<all_urls>",
 "tabs",
 "storage",
 "activeTab"
],
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
 }
}
....
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head> 
 ....
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="status" type="chckbox">
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $on = $("#status");
  //sends the settings to background to save it
  $on.on("click",function(){
    $obj = {"on":$on.prop("checked")}
    browser.runtime.sendMessage($obj);
    console.log("sending....");

  })
 })
```

What im trying to do is simply send a message to background script if the  check box in popup.html is checked.
The problem is I cannot access the browser namespace in popup.js because its not content script or background script. And i cannot access the check box from the content scrip as it not linked to popup.html (if its linked i get reference error browser is not defined. I've tried countless google searches and spent hours reading web extension docs still cannot find an answer how to go around it any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have good news for you - you **can** access the browser namespace in your browser action poupus, otherwise they would be pretty useless :)

Which means that something else is broken.

First, if you didn't do it yet, open 'browser toolbox' with Ctrl+Shift+Alt+I to see that you probably have a bit different kind of error there.

Then include this in your background.js :

```
function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("Message from somewhere: ", request);
}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

To actually **read** the message.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction

> JavaScript running in the popup gets access to all the same WebExtension APIs as your background scripts, but its global context is the popup, not the current page displayed in the browser. To affect web pages you need to communicate with them via messages.

**Edit**, unrelated:

```
$on = $("#status");
```

You do realize that by doing so you refer to/create a global variable '$on', right? Did you mean:

```
var $on = $("#status");
```

?

Comment: thanks for your answer but i dont know why i get Reference error browser is undefined in popup.js (errors in browser toolbox) do i need to add popup.js to manifest file?

Comment: @Noobrammer are you sure you're using Firefox? Isn't this Chrome? Because there is a small difference, Chrome uses the 'chrome' namespace instead of the standard 'browser'. So you have two options here, if you do use chrome - replace 'browser' with 'chrome' (will work on FX too) or use a polyfill, like this one: https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

Comment: ehhh, I can't edit, by "*will work on FX too*" I meant - it will work in Firefox in this simple scenario.

Comment: Edit: [this helped me with debugging the script properly. And i realized the problem. opening the popup.html in browser is not same as popup in browser action bar where and where only you can access the browser namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Debugging_popups)

Comment: heh, yeah :) Same with opening any other extension's page / js. You should do it from the extension (e.g. opening 'preferences' from extension list, 'page actions' from toolbar etc). Only this way you get the access to the extensions API. Glad you solved it :) BTW, opening things straight in the browser (without the ...extension:// prefix) is still useful on many occasions, like the UI design phase. On these occasions though, you might want to check if the `browser` object exists before using it. Just FWIW.